# Do you have another job 'to' me? VS Do you have another job 'for' me?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, parts-of-speech, to-infinitive, for

Which one is grammatical correct sentence?

> Do you have another job **to** me?

Or

> Do you have another job **for** me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

> Do you have *something* **for** me?
>
> Do you have *something* to give **to** me?